# Is it possible to intercept IOS separation notifications in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, events

Is it possible to listen for the new IOS-16 "Left Device Behind" event in Swift?

If the addEventListener method is how you do it, it's not clear how to label the desired event.

Comment: I would hope/assume that this isn't possible -- it seems like a privacy issue.

Comment: No more than any other privacy item like tracking where the phone is as it moves. The user can say no to the privacy request.